# On input:focus hide other inputs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to build a function so that when users are scrolling over input fields on my form, other input fields fade out...

Ive made a fiddle so that hopefully explains what im after better, but there is a label and input in each li, when the user hovers the li, the other fields ('li') should become semi transparent?

http://jsfiddle.net/WR4bJ/

Not sure if this is possible but any helps great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's the effect you're looking for:

**JS**

```
$('li').fadeTo(0, 0.3);
$('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.3);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="contact-form">
    <li><label>name</label><input type="text" /></li>
    <li><label>job</label><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

Greetings!

Comment: You're welcome :-). I hope that I helped. If it's the solution could you please mark it as the right answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this beautiful example :

http://jsfiddle.net/WR4bJ/12/